# change div height as per the table it contains

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dynamically re-sizing the div can be done using `display:table` in div css properties, but the tricky part is controlling it to certain height as the tables can be large and giving it vertical scroll.
So my question is how to limit the height even after applying `display:table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding a max-height to the div?

```
div {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You could then add overflow auto to make the content within the div scrollable.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.